# JetReport Server : Jet.Nimbus.Application consume all memory of the windows server

Tags: memory, server, reporting

We have a Windows Virtual Machine where JetReport server is installed (v2019 R2 20.7.20246.2 64-bits) Frequently the process "Jet.Nimbus.Application" consume a lot of memory (> 9GB) and the server doesn't respond any more.
We need to restart the server to fix the issue.

Do you know how is used this process "Jet.Nimbus.Application" ?

Is it possible to limit memory used by this process ?

Is it relative to a report launch by a user? If yes how is it possible to catch who execute the report, report name...

Is there a best practice to size the Memory allocate to the VM. Currently we setup 16GB of RAM.

Thank you